# TypeError: Cannot set property 'onscroll' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, onscroll

I am trying to create scroll effect, where on left side image is changing based on scroll position and right side is changing content while scrolling.

I am getting error when trying to execute `onscroll` javascript function. I am not sure what am I doing wrong - I am trying to use it in React App - is it possible that React has different rules to call this function?

I created example in here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-effect-37ecc

Comment: well. your `scrollingDiv` is null because the `getElementById("scrollContainer")` returns nothing. Since your component is not mounted, you wont have the div on the DOM. Try to put your code in `useEffect`

Comment: That actually solved it @Panther, I put the whole JS code in useEffect hook.

Comment: use "getElementByClassName" instead if getElementById
and give a unique class to that element.
also, add you call in useEffect. and use onScroll instead of onscroll

Answer (score 1):

I would use `useRef` for dom manipulation in React. That will be optimized.

```
import { useLayoutEffect, useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import classnames from "classnames";
import "./index.css";

const App = () => {
  // const scrollingDiv = document.getElementById("scrollContainer");
  // const img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
  // const img2 = document.getElementById("img2");

  const scrollingDiv = useRef(null);
  const image1 = useRef(null);
  const image2 = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    scrollingDiv.current.onscroll = function () {
    if (scrollingDiv.scrollTop < 250) {
      image1.current.src = "https://placeimg.com/250/100/arch";
      image2.current.src = "https://placeimg.com/250/100/animals";
    }

    if (scrollingDiv.current.scrollTop > 500) {
      image1.current.src = "https://placeimg.com/250/100/nature";
      image2.current.src = "https://placeimg.com/250/100/people";
    }
    if (scrollingDiv.current.scrollTop > 1000) {
      image1.current.src = "https://placeimg.com/250/100/tech";
      image2.current.src = "https://placeimg.com/250/100/any";
    }
  };

  }, []);


  return (
    <>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="left">
          <img ref={image1} id="img1" src="https://placeimg.com/250/100/arch" />
          <img ref={image2} id="img2" src="https://placeimg.com/250/100/animals" />
        </div>
        <div class="middle" ref={scrollingDiv} id="scrollContainer">
          <div class="in-middle">
            <div class="in-in-middle" id="1"></div>
            <div class="in-in-middle" id="2"></div>
            <div class="in-in-middle" id="3"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Or you can put direct listeners on the element as well using `onSroll` prop.

Also, don't forget to clear all the listeners in useEffect cleaning function, that way, you won't have any memory leak issues.

Answer (score 0):

normally, you would use useRef() function from react to get direct access to DOM elements, you can then use them like this:

```
const scrollingDiv = useRef(null);
<div id="scrollingSomething" ref={scrollingDiv}>
```

then you can manipulate the element using scollingDiv reference to the element

https://codesandbox.io/s/scroll-effect-forked-3nkbb